# Create a Tree from a Heterogenous Brace Initializer List

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

While learning C++, I decided to make a binary tree. Abridged to only class definitions and constructors, it looks like this:

```cpp
class Tree
{
public:
        class Node
        {
        public:
                Node(void) = default;
                virtual ~Node(void) = default;
        };
    
        class NullNode : public Node
        {
        public:
                NullNode(void) = default;
                ~NullNode(void) override = default;
        };
    
        class ValueNode : public Node
        {
        public:
                ValueNode(int value);
                ValueNode(int value, Node *left, Node *right);
                ~ValueNode(void) override;
        };
            
        // Constructors
        Tree(void);
        Tree(Node *root);
        ~Tree(void);
};
```

Constructing a list, I'd have to create it like this:

```cpp
Tree tree(new Node(new Node(1), new Node(3), 2),
          new Node(new Node(5), new Node(7), 6),
          4);
```

It feels terribly unsightly. I'd like to be able to construct the list like this instead:

```cpp
Tree tree({{{1}, {3}, 2}, {{5}, {7}, 6}, 4});
```

I've been looking into brace-enclosed initializer lists, but most of the text I find tend to view them more as variable-length lists of the same time, rather than maximum-length lists of different types. Is what I'm looking for possible?

Comment: Not too difficult, make the constructor argument a string, you can then use a parser to interpret the structure and create nodes dynamically. A common format for tree serialisation is `S-expressions`.

Comment: On paper it's possible (that's pretty much what [JSON for modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) does). Practically, it will likely take you more time than the entire tree project.